# Audio Player JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, audio-player

I am trying to build an audio player. I can't seem to get to get the on load function to work. My songs are in `E:\Music Player\Songs` file directory path.

```html
<script type=text/javascript>
  var songs = ["Nobody Compares To You - Gryffin.mp3", "Crawl Outta Love - Illenium.mp3",
    "Higher Ground - Odesza.mp3"
  ];
  var poster = ["Nobody Compares to You - Gryffin.png", "Awake - Illenium.jpg",
    "A Moment Apart  - Odesza.jpg"
  ];

  var songTitle = document.getElementById("songTitle");
  var fillBar = document.getElementById("fill");

  var song = new Audio();
  var currentSong = 0; // it points to the current song

  window.onload = playSong; // it will call the function playSong when window is load

  function playSong() {
    song.src = "./Songs/" + songs[currentSong]; //set the source of 0th song 
    songTitle.textContent = songs[currentSong]; // set the title of song
    song.play(); // play the song

  }
</script>
```

Comment: Please do not attach image of your code. You can edit your question and add code to your question.

Comment: is there a reason to not use images? Feel like its cleaner. Sorry, I am new here.

Comment: ah I see it takes care of formatting. Nevermind!

Comment: It has been discussed here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: can you check whether your onload is firing? if not update the code like`window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    console.log('All assets are loaded')
})`

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge, window.onload = playSong; is incorrectly calling playSong function.
window.onload = playSong(); // Brackets after a function name is mandatory.
Try this one.